# python 2.7 with mac osx lion: fn + delete and control + r

Tags: python, osx-lion

The sequences <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> that used to do recursive search / delete the following character do not work anymore in python 2.7 / Mac OSX Lion. Instead, a `~` appears each time I use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>. I am using `readline` for tab completion (which also had to be changed according to [python tab completion Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116038/python-tab-completion-mac-osx-10-7-lion)). Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks,
Bruno

Answer (score 3):

According to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline:

"Mac OS X, do not ship with GNU readline installed. The readline extension module in the standard library of Mac "system" Python uses NetBSD's editline (libedit) library instead, which is a readline replacement with a less restrictive software license."

So, you can install it with the command:

```
sudo easy_install readline
```

Else, you can use tcsh shortcuts; <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to delete the following character and <kbd>Ecp</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> for history search.

Answer (score 1):

For recursive search you can configure libedit by adding following line to `~/.editrc`

```
bind ^R em-inc-search-prev
```

or right from your `.pystartup` file

```
readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^R em-inc-search-prev")
```