# Where to put tab completion configuration in python?

Tags: python, autocomplete

[python tab completion Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116038/python-tab-completion-mac-osx-10-7-lion)

The above link shows that the following code can be used for autocompletion in python.

```
import readline
import rlcompleter
if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
    readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")
else:
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

But I don't see where to put it so that it can be loaded at startup. I tried `~/.pythonrc`, but it did not work.

Does anybody know what is the current way to load such a configuration automatically for an interactive python session?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? This should happen automatically on Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable to ~/.pythonrc. Put `PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc` into your .bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no need to set `~/.pythonrc`. For Mac, one just needs to set `~/.editrc` with the following content.

```
bind -v
bind ^I rl_complete
```

Comment: You can do that, but it's going to affect a lot more than just Python if you do. That may be a good thing or a bad thing.