# Getting pdb to have tab completion in OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

I am trying to get tab completion to work while running pdb on OS X 10.10.5.  I have installed the homebrew version of python 2.7.13 because it [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116038/python-tab-completion-mac-osx-10-7-lion) (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675370/tab-completion-in-python-interpreter-in-os-x-terminal)) that Apple does not ship with a functional readline.  If I have a trivial script, `trivial.py`

```
var1 = "this"
var2 = "is annoying"
```

and I run `/usr/local/bin/python -m pdb trivial.py` and on the first entry I enter `import readline, rlcompleter;` I subsequently can get tab completion.  However, if I put in my .pdbrc

```
import readline
import rlcompleter
```

tab completion does **not** work.  How is this not the exact same thing?  Shouldn't tab completion work when put in my .pdbrc?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behavior on linux.

ie. with no .pdbrc

```
$ python3 -m pdb foo.py
(Pdb) in<tab> gives interact
(Pdb) interact
(Pdb) import rlcompleter
(Pdb) in<tab>
(Pdb) in input(  int(
```

If I have import rlcompleter in my .pdbrc I only get interact when I type in.  I get this same result even after I import rlcompleter.

```
$ python3 -m pdb -c 'import rlcompleter' foo.py
```

Also prevents tab completion.

Comparing the output of

```
$ python3 -vv -m pdb -c 'import rlcompleter' foo.py
```

and

```
$ python3 -vv -m pdb foo.py
```

resulted in a segfault so I would consider this a bug.  I suggest you file a bug.  Mention something about the import rlcompleter could be missing the Pdb completeionkey=setting being overwritten or the cmd module could be misinitialized.  FWIW here is the source I was looking at to gleam some additional info. [Pdb source](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r31rc1/Lib/pdb.py)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498182/)

Using this method I was able to get the tab completion to work.  His code uses a .pdbrc in the source dir and a hidden python script in the home dir.  The file has comments where to split the file into two parts.